# Does the Extended Ending DLC contain the Synthesis Choice?

Tags: mass-effect-3

When i saw my dad complete the game i remember him only having 2 choices, to destroy or to control the Reapers and i remember he chose to destroy, i remember the scene well as i remember seeing the shorts of the Illusive Man and Anderson and since i hadn't played the game i saw thinking *did the Illusive Man try and control them already and got all scorched as a result of what i saw in the cutscene*, i also remember the 2 choices was Blue and Red and had been wondering if the control option was Paragon and the destroy option was renegade.

Obviously my dad didn't have the Extended Ending DLC so when i got to the final choice i got the 2 choices he got, after listening to the Catalyst about what would happen to me i was thinking of control as i would probably end up like Madoka from Pellua Magi Madoka Magica, however then the Catalyst game me a third option to merge Synthetic and Organic, the Synthesis Choice.

Now i am unsure what decisions my dad made up to Mass Effect 3 so i am wondering if the Synthesis Choice was added because i have the Extended Ending DLC or if i had done something throughout the Mass Effect Trilogy which allowed it and if so what was it.

Comment: It's called "extended cut" and not "extended ending" DLC. The choice count still depends on the military strength. I had 5 options last time. I am not sure what the 4th was, but the 5th was choose nothing and let ppl die.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Synthesis was in the game originally. In my particular case, I had been playing all night right after it came out, trying to finish the game before I had to leave town, and didn't really understand that you could walk to the left, right, or ahead; and just walked straight ahead and chose it "by accident".

However, there is a [minimum EMS](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-3/End_Game_Chart_-_With_Spoilers) required to make that choice available: according to that site, 2800. Dunno if that number was adjusted with the Extended Ending.

Comment: I don't remember what my EMS was but i did get the achievement in regards to delivering most of the assets, i also didn't realize that Shepard could live, might just read up on that ending

Comment: The problem is the "Effective" part of EMS, which is the [Galactic Readiness](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Galaxy_at_War) rating, which defaults to 50%. Half of the 4000 to get the achievement is not enough. You have to do stuff outside the (main single-player) game to increase it.

Comment: yeh i remember doing every side mission and getting (mostly) all the assets from other galaxies, there were a few that no matter how much i tried i couldn't pick up anything but i began to ignore the EMS when the effective part passed minimum which is why i don't remember my number, i know that i didn't do the Galaxy at War thing so it was always 50%